# Update page content with several Ajax calls that depends on output from previous call

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I need to update page content with data from external php scripts called in specific order.

On the page there are a number of divs where I want to put data collected via a php script (getdata.php). Data is collected continuously over and over again since it changes.

The problem is that I need to get the data in the correct order since each call is dependent on the output from the previous call, so

- first get data for div1 using getdata.php?id=1
- reply will contain data1 plus xid
- show data1 in div 1 and
- get data for div 2 using getdata.php?id=xid (id from first call)
- reply will contain data2 plus new xid2
- show data2 in div2 and
- get data for div 3 using getdata.php?id=xid2 (id from second call)
- etc

The number of divs can vary on the page and so the no of calls can vary. The number of divs is "known" when page is loaded first time so it can be sent with the onload javascript call

Tried using XMLHttpRequest but can't get it to work synchronously

Also am not sure if that is a good idea since it will probably lock the browser if synchronous and it can take 10-15 seconds for each call

So I suppose the best solution would be to usa a standard asynchronous XMLHttpRequest in order to not lock the browser and then initiate the next call when readyState == 4 in onreadystatechange function, but how can I make this a loop?

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use synchronous XMLHttpRequest. That will indeed make the browser UI unresponsive.

What you could do is call a new XMLHttpRequest within the success callback of the previous one. This is actually a common pattern for chaining Ajax requests, one after the other.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url:  '/getdata.php?id=1',

   success: function (data) {
      // update div 1 ...

      $.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url:  '/getdata.php?id=' + data.id,

         success: function (data) {
            // update div 2 ...

            // and so on ...
         }
      });
   }
});
```

Further to your comment below, this is one way to refactor the above such that you can repeat the process "recursively" for a number of times (determined when the page is loaded).

```
function callAjax (id, n) {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url:  '/getdata.php?id=' + id,

      success: function (data) {
         // update div
         $(data.id).text(data.content);

         // loop recursively
         if (n > 0) callAjax(data.id, n - 1);
      }
   });
}

callAjax(1, 50);  // this will start the process which will "loop" 
                  // for 50 times. The id of the first request 
                  // will be 1, and subsequent ones will be obtained
                  // from the previous request.
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But how can I do this for x divs over and over again in loops? It's the first time I use XMLHttpRequest and I am not getting it 
It can be 10 or 50 calls and I do not want to have xxx number of nesed functions. Or am I misunderstanding your code

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. 
So I suppose I just call a setInterval when page is loaded to call the callAjax each xx seconds

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @1kjg: Actually there is no need to call `setInterval()`. Simply call `callAjax(1, x);` where `x` is the number of divs you have. Then the function will call it self automatically for `x` times, and it will update the querystring parameter from the response of the previous request. My example is assuming you're using JSON responses, but you can obviously use any other format: XML, comma separated, etc...

Comment: Since the data is to be be collected all the time I need to have something that restarts the loop that collects data to all divs (either directly when first loop is ready or after xx seconds). Probably a setTimeout when loop is ready might be better, but I also need to be able to stop the loop and restart it so having a handle via setInterval seems easier (need to stop the loop if the visitor adds data in a form field. That data is to be put to the getdata.php (and from there to another page) and when reply is OK from the put, the loop will be restarted again.